# Ruby on Rails remote form not updating the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

**UPDATE**

I have mange to get it working by changing the Model call from

```
@comments = VideoComment.all(:conditions => { :video_id => @video.id}, :limit => 5, :order => :created_at) 

@comments = VideoComment.last(5).reverse
```

It works, but it gives me the last video comments from **all** the videos whereas I only want those from the current video (`@video.id`).

Any clue on how to do that?

---

I have a `Video`controller and a `VideoComments` controller which manages the comments for the `Video` controller. I am trying to make my remote form update the comments list with ajax but it does not seem to work. Can you find what I did wrong?

HTML code of the show page :

```
- if current_user
    #comment-form
      = render 'video_comments/comment_form'
  %ul
    #comments
      = render @comments
```

video_comments/_comment_form.html.haml

```
= form_for current_user.video_comments.build(:video_id => params[:id]), :remote => true do |f|
  .form-fields
    .comment-content
      = f.text_area :content, rows:2
    = f.hidden_field :video_id
    = f.hidden_field :user_id
    .submit-form
      = f.submit "Add a comment", :class => "btn btn-default "
```

The `Video_Comments`controller `create`action :

```
 def create
    @comment = VideoComment.create(params[:video_comment])
    @video = @comment.video
    @comments = VideoComment.all(:conditions => { :video_id => @video.id}, :limit => 5, :order => :created_at) 
    render :toggle      
 end
```

The `toggle.js.erb` file which manages the page changes :

```
$("#comment-form").html("<%= escape_javascript render 'comment_form' %>");
$("#comments").html("<%= escape_javascript render @comments %>");
```

Comment: is the new comment in `@comments`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3 you can do

```
@comments = VideoComment.where(:video_id => @video.id).order(:created_at).limit(5)
```

Or if you have relations properly defined you can also do

```
@comments = @video.comments.order(:created_at).limit(5)
```

Comment: You again ismaelga! :P The second solution is what I was looking for!

Comment: you may want to see this article http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface